# During PayPal redirect to pay, Customer loses session on return - on tablet/android

Tags: php, android, session, mobile, paypal

THe problem only occures on tablets (perhaps phones too) - tested on nexus 7 and ipad2. It works fine on my desktop computer & laptop and everyone elses computers.

I have a homemade shop made with PHP.  User gets redirected to paypal to pay, and upon return all of a sudden his session is gone (or empty?), as he is no longer logged in (thus can't see the order summary, as i require the user to be logged in).

It does this on both Chrome & Firefox browsers (android tablet - nexus 7) and on ipads' safari. It appears it also clears the "local cookie".

As i said, it works fine on regular desktop computers - so yes... i did restart the session and stuff on the users return (and every other page involved).

Whats the best way of dealing with this?

Am i doing something wrong or is everything working as intended for tablets?

My solution atm would be to simply reset the required session variables on the return (i would identify the user with the token_id), without doing a proper login/password check - seems risky, or no?

**edit ->

I just wanted to add that the session (and its variables) are retained IF the users clicks on "cancel" on the paypal site during the payment process. ** eidt2 -> which is odd, because both return links run the same script

WHAT IS GOING ON :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found "a" solution after a day full of head scratching.

If i add `die();` right after the header redirect in my paypal processing file, it works on tablets.

Not sure why it worked fine before on desktop, but this "fix" seems to solve my lost session problem for tablets.